# Is it possible to use the Absinthe plugin for Elixir with Neo4J

Tags: neo4j, elixir, graphql

I know it is possible to use Elixir with Neo4J, there are working examples using a bolt wrapper. But that doesn't use Absthine and will not be using GraphQL. Is it possible to use the same schema file you would use if you say had a Postgres DB or any of the more traditional databases?

```
query do
 @desc "Get an item by ID"
 field :item, :item do

  @desc "The ID of the item"
  arg :id, type: :id

  resolve fn %{id: id}, _ ->
   {:ok, Map.get(@fake_db, id)}
 end
end
```

This is a typical schema file for a traditional database whether that be SQL or Non-SQL, could you follow a similar pattern usine Neo4J? or would you have to implement it without GraphQL using the method in this Git Repo https://github.com/florinpatrascu/bolt_sips ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have no experience with Neo4j, but there's nothing stopping you from using the data storage of your choice with absinthe. The schema definition is database-agnostic, but obviously the resolvers you write will need to run Neo4j queries.

As a side note, access to relational DBs is typically handled with ecto, via the [absinthe_ecto](https://github.com/absinthe-graphql/absinthe_ecto) package. However, this is merely a convenience wrapper around the batching feature of absinthe. Without Ecto, you can just use [absinthe batching](https://hexdocs.pm/absinthe/Absinthe.Middleware.Batch.html) directly.

Comment: Thanks, that helped a lot